# PHP/MySQL Array Exclude

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've got a page that displays all of a users' photos but I'm looking to exclude the default profile picture which is thumb-default.png. How do I do that?

```
<?

$getphotos = mysql_query("SELECT ID, Link FROM images WHERE MemberID = '$vid'");
while($iph = mysql_fetch_array($getphotos))
{
$pID = $iph['ID'];
$pLINK = $iph['Link'];

echo "

<li><a href=\"members_image/$vid/$pLINK\" rel=\"prettyPhoto[gallery]\"><img src='/members_image/$vid/thumb-$pLINK' width='105'></a></li>

";


}
```

Thank you!! :-)

Comment: you know you can use combination of double quote and single quote to get rid of escape character `\\`

Comment: do not use short tags. Do escape variables passed to query.

Comment: @NullPonyPointer That is true, but if doing the single quote in HTML makes in 'technically' invalid HTML, and if doing it on the outside, requires concatenation of multiple string which adds more code that really isn't needed, nor does it help with readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add at the end of your query `AND Link != 'thumb-default.png'`

```
$getphotos = mysql_query("SELECT ID, Link FROM images WHERE MemberID = '$vid' AND Link != 'thumb-default.png'");
```

This excludes every entry with this link to be selected.

Comment: I think 'Link' should have the value default.png (not thumb-default.png)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above and also it is better to use this,

```
while($iph = mysql_fetch_object($getphotos))
{
$pID = $iph->ID;
$pLINK = $iph->Link;

}
```

Because I think mysql_fetch_array, prefers array element keys as numbers. $iph[0], $iph[1]...

I think for alpha key elements, you use

```
mysql_fetch_assoc
```